# {"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet"} error when accessing AWS elasticsearch endpoint

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-cognito

I have an AWS elasticsearch service, and have configured cognito authentication as well, Now I'm not able to access my elasticsearch endpoint, I get the " **{"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet"}** " error. Below is my JSON Access policy -

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<<Account_Number>>:role/Cognito_kibana_identitiesAuth_Role"
      },
      "Action": "es:ESHttp*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-2:<<Account_Number>>:domain/<<Domain_Name>>/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I understand this might be a duplicate question, but I couldn't find how to change my access policy given that I have cognito access enabled also. I'm pretty new to ELK. Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

If an authenticated user have got this error, then the error message would contain `User: x:x:x:x is not authorized...` but the error you got saying `User: anonymous is not authorized...`. Which indicates the user is not authenticated, the issue is with the Cognito authentication or in role assumption.

1. Are you directly using an unauthenticated user to assume Cognito id pool auth role?
2. Please check the trust policy for the auth role configured with Cognito identity pool. It need to be follow this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-trust-and-permissions.html

For authenticated users, `"cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"` need to be used in condition.

Comment: I can login to kibana using the username and password that I have setup, But cannot access the elasticsearch endpoint or APIs using command prompt, can you guide me what I need to do inorder to do that ? 

FYI - I currently use kibana dev. console to do the API calls, but I need it from command prompt

Comment: @VidhyaDhara AFAIK, it is not possible using Command Prompt (using AWS CLI) or any AWS SDK. Because, the flow of Authentication between Kibana and Cognito happens in OAuth 2.0 protocol. Which is a browser based protocol. The protocol uses cookies stored in browser, in CLI or SDK it will be not possible to store cookie as a browser do.